# Disable display countdown during the use of Google Maps

Tags: gps, google-maps

When I use [Google Maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) for my [Samsung Galaxy S](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S), after a while the display goes dark and the GPS disconnects. Is there a way to disable the display countdown during the usage of Google Maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [Tasker](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) application to change the screen timeout and brightness (as well as the GPS) when I use Maps or Navigation.  I turn on GPS and disable timeout when starting Maps/Navigation and turn them off on exiting.  Tasker allows you to specify certain tasks that are activated when opening/closing and application.  It has several other features and uses, but I find it works well for the problem you are having.